# python-can Keep getting the same message(id)

Tags: python-3.x, can-bus, python-can

I'm more of a HW engineer who's currently trying to use Python at work. What I want to accomplish via Python is read the CAN-FD output from the DUT and use it for monitoring purposes in the measurement setup. But, I think I didn't get the correct result. Because it shows the same message(id) even there so much more. Based on my understanding from other examples, this should shows the stream of all the messages since there was no filters. Is there anyone who can help me solve this issue or have the similar experience?

```
import can

def _get_message(msg):
    return msg

bus = can.interface.Bus(bustype='vector',app_name ='app', channel=1, bitrate=500000)    
buffer = can.BufferedReader()
can.Notifier(bus,[_get_message,buffer])    
while True:
    msgs = bus.recv(None)
    print(msgs)
```

Comment: I have no idea what you mean with "it shows the same message(id) even there're so much more". There is more? More what, where? Even though there are other id getting sent on the bus?

Comment: Sorry, I definitely was not clear enough. There was a MATLAB code that could tell how actual bus output looked like.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what you expected to see on your bus, but I assume there are a lot of different messages on it.

Simplify your problem to start with - set up a bus which has only a single message on it at a low rate.  You might have to write some code for that, or you might get some tools which can send periodic messages with counters in for example. Make sure you can capture that correctly first. Then add a second message at a faster rate.

You will proably learn a selection of useful things from these exercises which mean that when you go back to your full-system you have more success, or at least have more ideas on what to debug :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thanks for the answers and comments. the root cause was the incorrect HW configuration for the interface. I thought if HW configuration is wrong in the first place, there will be no output at all. But it turned out it is not. After proper configuration, I could see the output stream I expected.